# electron startDrag target OS path

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have been playing around with the file system drag and drop functionality of Electron apps.

**What I want:**

1. I need to know , if I drag a div out of electron app into OS , 
   I just want to know target Os path.
2. I am not interested in copying file operation to that path as i have my custom logic

**Similar Solutions:**
I know about these solutions but I am not interested in as my goal is know target OS path. All these issues address drag and drop files out of electron app into OS .

1. [Is it possible to drag a remote file out of Electron App onto the file system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43209509/is-it-possible-to-drag-a-remote-file-out-of-electron-app-onto-the-file-system)
2. https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/native-file-drag-drop

**File-Zilla displaying path after drag onto OS**
[image]

Comment: did you find any workaround for this issue or something?

Comment: No answer yet? I did the same with C# in .NET. But I needed to subscribe to the OS events for creating files...So I created an empty file, used that for the drag and drop and then when I get the "create" event from the OS, I knew the location, so I could start the download of the file...Not pretty, but it works. But now I still need that for Node.js / Electron