# Getting dropped file path in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, electron, electron-packager

In electron, there's a feature where you can drag out an element and drop it on your desktop [as seen in this example](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/native-file-drag-drop). I've searched all over the place for a possible example or GitHub issue I can refrence but the closest I got to a working solution was to simply drag out a filler file which then the system searches for and provides me with a valid path.

I've noticed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49134283/electron-startdrag-target-os-path) question which seems to have gone unanswered unfortunately (and the Electron team also seems unintrested in adding onto the `startDrag` function anytime soon)

As mentioned earlier, I've tried saving this temporary dummy file which then gets searched for and the respective path is given. Not very ideal for large systems just for a simple feature addition on the Electron teams end which is kind of disappointing. I'd also like to refrence [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/12144) which I feel was closed down by the Electron team in an effort to effectively ditch their community.

Anyway, I apologize for the unesscary blabber and any efforts you will put into helping solve this issue would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It's only possible through hacks like you mention. Electron/Chrome or other browsers do not supply the real os path for such events for security reasons.

Comment: Hey Brahma Dev -- I'm pretty sure in `main.js` (where the electron part of the app exist) is where the event occurs

Comment: Electron is a layer on top of chromium. Your interaction is between chromium and OS, hence the behaviour. Electron can't help, unless they start changing chromium to support this feature in the way you expect it to work. Which they may do ultimately, but it hasn't happened yet.